# CSS Hover only on text?

Tags: html, css, text, hover

If I have the following HTML with a custom CSS class:

```css
.custom_list_item {
  color: black;
}

.custom_list_item:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom_list_item">Test</div>
```

This makes it so when I hover over the entire box, it makes the text red. Is there a way to make sure this only happens when I hover over just the text itself?

Comment: you can wrap the text inside a paragraph element and add your style to it. Is it clear to you?

Comment: As @08691 said below, this is a simple display concept.

A div by default has display block, so that div gets the full space available.
If you want that .custom_list_item. get only the content width, just you have to modify block display  by default given to DIVs with display: inline-block;
Just:

.custom_list_item {display: inline-block;  color: black; }

Comment: @AlbertoFortes No, actually that's not what I'm trying to accomplish. Since this is meant to be used as a list item, if I set the display to inline-block it would still hover on the entire box if there is another element that has a wider content block. The span works perfectly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap it in a `span`. A `p` would stretch over the full width of `div`.

```css
.custom_list_item {
    color: black;
}

.custom_list_item span:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom_list_item"><span>Test</span></div>
```

Comment: Yes thanks, this is perfect. I was using a p earlier, and realized that it didn't help my situation.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it in span then style span:

```css
.custom_list_item {
  color: black;
}

.custom_list_item span:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom_list_item">
  <span>Test</span>
</div>
```

Comment: If you change `p` to `span` you have a working solution ;)

Comment: Yea. That's a better Idea. Updated my answer in respect of your advice and reputation :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change that div's [display property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop) from `block` to `inline-block`. No extra elements like spans necessary.

```css
.custom_list_item {
  color: black;
  display:inline-block;
}

.custom_list_item:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom_list_item">Test</div>
```

Divs are block level elements by default and will take up the full width of their parent element.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap a span for your div and set span:hover

```css
.custom_list_item {
    color: black;
}

span:hover{
    color: red;
}

div{
border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom_list_item"><span>Test</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

also you can write :hover with space after .custom_list_item as below:

```css
.custom_list_item {
    color: black;
}

.custom_list_item :hover{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom_list_item"><span>Test</span></div>
```